# write.xlsx function not working

Tags: r, xlsx, r-xlsx

I am trying to use .xlsx library but function write.xlsx is returning error that such can not be found.

When I am installing library(xlsx) in log I can read:

```
Error : .onLoad nie powiodło się w funkcji 'loadNamespace()' dla pakietu 'rJava', szczegóły:
  wywołanie: fun(libname, pkgname)
  błąd:  No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re-installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: pakiet ‘xlsx’ został zbudowany w wersji R 3.3.2 
2: pakiet ‘rJava’ został zbudowany w wersji R 3.3.3 
Error: pakiet ‘rJava’ nie mógł zostać załadowany
```

Java is up to date.

Comment: You may want to try `openxlsx`, which doesn't depend on Java.

Comment: @Jaap Installed and run readxl library. So it is JAVA problem?

Comment: @RafMil - need `writexl` to write output. See my answer for a working example of `writexl::write_xlsx()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The code in the original post fails because the `xlsx` package uses the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) Java API to Excel, and therefore requires the `rJava` package. In turn, the `rJava` package requires a working, compatible version the Java Runtime Environment to be installed on the machine and accessible from R.

One can tell whether Java is accessible from R / RStudio via the `system()` function.

```
> system("java -version")
java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
>
```

There are at least four sets of R packages used for working with Excel files, including:

1. xlsx -- requires rJava package
2. XLConnect -- requires rJava package
3. openxlsx -- does not require rJava package
4. readxl / writexl -- does not require rJava package

For options 3 and 4, the solution is simply to use `install.packages()` to install the desired package (as noted in another answer by @Linus), once you've updated R to the latest version.

```
install.packages("openxlsx") 
library(openxlsx)
```

or

```
install.packages(c("readxl","writexl")) 
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
```

### A Working Example: Write to Excel File

```
library(writexl)
data <- data.frame(matrix(runif(100),nrow=10,ncol=10))
write_xlsx(data,"./data/simpleExcel.xlsx")
```

...and the output:

[image]

### If You Must Use rJava...

Unfortunately, options 1 and 2 are considerably more complicated than "install Java." If one must use `xlsx` or needs the `rJava` package to support other R packages, installation of Java varies significantly by operating system.

**Windows:** one must install a version of Java whose architecture is compatible with R (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit). One may consider installing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions because some Windows programs installed on the computer may require 32-bit Java vs. 64-bit. With RStudio, one can configure R to use the 32-bit version of R if only 32-bit Java is installed on the machine.

**Mac OS X:** one must install Java and run a series of commands that are documented on the [rJava Issues GitHub page](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/86), including executing an R script to reconfigure Java for R.

**Linux:** one needs to install Java using the package installer tool appropriate for the version of Linux, and then configure R to use it. For example, in Ubuntu one would install with the advanced packaging tool.

```
 sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk # openjdk-9-jdk has some installation issues
 sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Answer (score 3):

xlsx needs Java. Please install the current Java version from https://www.java.com/de/

and watch out, that both R and java are either 32bit or 64bit as it is stated in the error message

> ... and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.

Or use *writexls* or *openxlsx*. They are not depending on Java (Thanks @Len)

Comment: The OP asked about writing an Excel file. Therefore, the correct package is writexl, not readxl.

Comment: Thank you. This library can be run without any error. So it is JAVA out of date version or something like this? Architecture is the same for R and JAVA. Thanks for your help folks.

Comment: @RafMil - first thing needed to diagnose the Java problem is to know which operating system you're using. As I note in my answer to this question, installation of Java runtime with R varies significantly by operating system.